# Check if MySQL server is alive

Tags: mysql

How can I check the readiness of a MySQL database that has a user and a password already set?

Without password the command should be:

```
mysqladmin ping -h localhost
```

Bin in my test environment the MySQL database already has a password set in the environment variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` named `abc123`. Simply providing the password with `-p` doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
mysqladmin ping -h localhost -p abc123
```

On average the MySQL database takes about 20 seconds to start.

Comment: 20 seconds sounds like a long time.

Comment: 20 seconds might not be a long time if there are a lot of tables or Socrates doesn't shutdown the system cleanly before powering off.

Comment: DO NOT use the root account for normal access to your DBMS.

Answer (score 5):

Check the manual please https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqladmin.html

You can supply  an account/user name and password with the `--user` and `--password` command line switches to log on.

Depending on your needs you might simply check the exit code of a `mysqladmin ping` without supplying any credentials as that already gives you a database server status :

> `ping`
>
> Check whether the server is available. The return status from mysqladmin is 0 if the server is running, 1 if it is not. **This is 0 even in case of an error such as Access denied,** because this means that the server is running but refused the connection, which is different from the server not running.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25503412 for some other considerations regarding the use of `mysqladmin ping` as a health check

Answer (score 0):

there should be no space between the -p and the provided password if you are providing a password on the command line.

the desired command should be

```
mysqladmin ping -h localhost -pabc123
```

not

```
mysqladmin ping -h localhost -p abc123
```